# How can I install any packages from Github?

Tags: r

I want to install quantreg packages from Github.How can I get the source of this packages? Thanks!

```
     devtools::install_github("quantreg")
     Error in username %||% getOption("github.user") %||% stop("Unknown 
      username.") : 
      Unknown username.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to specify the **user** *AND* the **package** name, separated by a "/".

I personally prefer using `remotes` as opposed to `devtools` for GitHub:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("efriedland/friedland") # my GitHub name, my r package
```

So perhaps you need `"cran/quantreg"`?